# how to make thinner new.lines on pine

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to make horizontal lines on trading view,
but they keeps too thick,
and I realized maybe it is because it plots lots of simultaneos lines.

I want like this but the thinnest possible line:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
var tmepo=timestamp("2021-05-14T00:00:00")
var tmempo=timestamp("2021-05-15T00:00:00")
line.new(x1=tmepo, y1=4000, x2=tmempo, y2=4000,extend=extend.right,width=0,xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

However I realised it is plotting a beam like this but collapsed:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
var tmepo=timestamp("2021-05-15T00:00:00")
var tmempo=timestamp("2021-05-15T00:00:00")
line.new(x1=tmepo, y1=4000, x2=time, y2=4200,extend=extend.none,width=0,xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
var tmepo   = timestamp("2021-05-14T00:00:00")
var tmempo  = timestamp("2021-05-15T00:00:00")
var myLine  = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time) // define myLine
var price   = 4000

if barstate.islast
    // move myLine
    line.set_xy1(myLine, tmepo,  price)
    line.set_xy2(myLine, tmempo, price)
```